# "where else" word usage in a sentence (phrase)

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say you just expressed your *annoyance* to a taxi driver who happens to be *texting* while driving you around.

> What the! **where else** can you see a driver who has got the nerve to text while driving!

Can you use this word combination (where-else)? I just made this one up taken from "what else", "anywhere else" words. I can't see any result upon googling the word "where else".

Comment: I have a mistake in your sentence: **who have got.** It should be **who has got**. *Have* is only used for plural things or the first-person singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could say

> Where else can you see a driver who has got the nerve to text while driving?

which would emphasize that you think such behavior is characteristic of the current location but would not be expected or acceptable elsewhere.